# XSLT translate() not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I created a function to replace commas and dashes with a space, the issue is the it is removing the comma and dashes but it is not replacing it with the dash.

For example I have a user last name Smith-Jones when the transformation is processed I end up with SmithJones not Smith Jones.

My function is:

```
<xsl:function name="this:prepareText">

   <xsl:param name="input-String"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(($input-String),'&#044;&#045;', ' '))"/>

</xsl:function>
```

Seems like I must be missing something small here, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma case was actually probably working correctly because the third argument to `translate` contains a space in the first character position (corresponding to `&#044;` -- comma), but the dash case wouldn't be because there is no second replacement character, so dash would be replaced by nothing.

Just add another space to the third argument of `translate` and it'll work fine:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(($input-String),'&#044;&#045;', '  '))"/>
```